# Magento2: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, xml

I added one custom `HelloWorld` module in a fresh `Magento 2` installation and I got the following error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the
>   document in Entity, line: 8 in
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 365

What can be the exact cause for this issue?

<del>I get this error even when I install the [sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage) from Magento repo. I have not done any edits to the sample module.</del>

It was my custom module causing the problem. Sample module from magento github works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My module was named `Chapagain_HelloWorld`. The problematic XML file was `app/code/Chapagain/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

I don't know what exactly caused the problem. I just replaced the code present there with a similar code from another module and changed the module name, route id, and front name, and then the module worked without any error. But, I could not see any difference between the replaced code and the problematic code.

Here the code of my `routes.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Chapagain_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: I faced this issue with empty routes.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like one of your XML files in your module has bad syntax. Make sure every opening tag has a closing tag, and that there is only one root level XML tag per XML file.

Comment: I get this error even when I install the sample module from Magento repo. I have not done any edits to the sample module. https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage

Comment: When do you get the error? Somewhere along the line you may have accidentally changed an XML file; maybe you accidentally deleted a `>` or similar. Can you look at all recently modified XML files?

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.0 remove the XML version tag at starting of your XML files.

I don't know why but after removing it my code starts working, while the above works for version>2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where is empty file and you are using linux. Use this command to get list of empty files.

open terminal and type
`find  /path/to/dest -type d -empty`